# Facebook Messenger Customer Chat Plugin on mobile website

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger

I'm trying to insert Custom Chat plugin on my website. It works perfectly but it does not look good on mobile. I just want it to have the page width, but it looks like this:

[image]

Here's my HTML code, it's really simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Otto Bot</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- Your customer chat code -->
    <div 
      class="fb-customerchat" 
      attribution="setup_tool" 
      page_id="<MY-PAGE-ID>" 
      logged_in_greeting="Hablemos?" 
      logged_out_greeting="Hablemos?"
      minimized='false'>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just copied and pasted the code given in my page settings. I've already tried with the instructions given in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/web-plugins/#customer_chat

Comment: First of all, you can not manipulate any of the Facebook plugins in ways other than the configuration options provided allow. Secondly, that screenshot rather looks as if most of the problem might rather be due to the fact that you did nothing at all to make this “page” mobile-friendly to begin with. Not even a viewport meta tag, so the browser just displays this is if it was a “desktop site” and simply scales everything down.

Comment: Thanks! I just had to add the viewport meta tag. Sorry for the silly question, I just wanted a website that displayed the messenger plugin but I had never built a responsive website.

Answer (score 2):

Just had to add a viewport meta tag in the head section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Otto Bot</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- Your customer chat code -->
    <div 
      class="fb-customerchat" 
      attribution="setup_tool" 
      page_id="<MY-PAGE-ID>" 
      logged_in_greeting="Hablemos?" 
      logged_out_greeting="Hablemos?"
      minimized='false'>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```